# Increasing my Raspberry pi Access point connectivity with a USB travel router

Tags: networking, wifi

I want to use a travel router to increase connection of my raspberry pi AP. How can I use the USB travel router as wlan1. Then Use wlan1 as my AP interface.

Answer (score 1):

`"How can I use the USB travel router as wlan1"`... IMHO, your question is far too vague to answer because it depends largely upon which travel router you use, and other specifics you have not included in your question.

I will say that you can use a travel router with your RPi, and will make these suggestions:

1. Read [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask),
2. Select a specific travel router from one of the "usual sources", and read the documentation. FWIW, [I like these](https://www.gl-inet.com/) OK.
3. Before you invest too much in this idea, perhaps give some thought to the *"other issues"* you may encounter in your anticipated use-case (traveling, I presume). For example: will batteries be required, Internet connectivity?, etc. I say this not to discourage, only to share my view that RPi may not be the best "traveling companion".